# How to re-scale image between 0 and 1 using PIL?

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

There is a method in Keras called ImageDataGenerator that scales images, that would look liks this:

```
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
```

I want to do the same scaling of an image, but using PIL. I have this code:

```
file_list = ['image1.jpg', 'image2.jpg']
for i in file_list:
  test_image = image.load_img(i,target_size=(150,150))
  images = image.img_to_array(test_image)
  images = image.img_to_array(test_image)
  images = np.expand_dims(images, axis=0)
```

Could someone show me how to add 'rescale the image' similar to that of ImageDataGenerator, using PIL? I can see the re-size parameter in the documentation [here](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html) but not re-scale?

Comment: I see the question is tagged `keras` and you say something about `ImageDataGenerator` which appears to come from Keras. I assume this is intended to help explain what you want, but that doesn't work very well - people shouldn't have to know, or be familiar with, Keras to answer a question about PIL. Please try to explain what you want directly, instead.

Comment: thanks, I removed the tag and then I just explained why I had mentioned keras, it's to show the same effect I'm trying to get, but using PIL instead of keras.

Comment: Hold on - in the second code example, is `image` supposed to be the *module* `tf.keras.preprocessing.image`? And the point is that `images = image.img_to_array(test_image)` gives you a Numpy array, that you want to rescale? Then the question doesn't actually have anything to do with PIL at all; you can rescale this array the same way you would rescale any other Numpy array - e.g. `images /= 255.0`.

Comment: Oh, you want to *replace* the Keras code with completely PIL code? In *that* case, you can directly pass a PIL Image instance to `np.array`, and then work with the array as usual. There are other ways, too. It is [pretty easy](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=pil+image+to+array) to [research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) that kind of thing. (If you are doing heavy image processing work with Numpy and PIL, you might also want to look into imageio.)